# Could not resolve property: current_profit_percpa of: com.uforic.optionstrader.domain.StrategyExitReport

Tags: jpa

I am writing a JPA query trying to fetch columns from two tables. Fetching columns from different tables is not the issue, but when I select SUM OF any column, I get an error.

This is my query.

```
 entityManager().createQuery("SELECT NEW com.uforic.optionstrader.domain.StrategyExitReport(sum(o.current_profit_percpa),p.strategyType) FROM StrategyExitReport o, "
+ "PositionCombination p WHERE o.positionCombination=p.id and "
+ "o.user=:user and o.tickTime in "
+ "(SELECT MAX(s.tickTime) FROM StrategyExitReport s group by s.positionCombination) "
+ "group by p.strategyType",StrategyExitReport.class).setParameter("user", user).getResultList();
```

This is the entity class and I have defined the particular constructor to fetch those columns

```
public class StrategyExitReport{

public StrategyExitReport(){}

public StrategyExitReport(Double currentProfitPercPA,int strategyType)
{
 this.clientId = strategyType;
 this.currentProfitPercPA = currentProfitPercPA;
}
public StrategyExitReport(int strategyType)
{
 this.clientId = strategyType;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "position_combination_id")
private PositionCombination positionCombination;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private Userr user;

private double payoff;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "S-")
private Date tickTime;

private Double currentProfitPercPA;

private double totalDelta;
private double totalTheta;
private double totalGamma;
private long clientId;
}
```

This is the error I am getting

> Could not resolve property: current_profit_percpa of: com.uforic.optionstrader.domain.StrategyExitReport [SELECT NEW com.uforic.optionstrader.domain.StrategyExitReport(sum(o.current_profit_percpa),p.strategyType) FROM com.uforic.optionstrader.domain.StrategyExitReport o, com.uforic.optionstrader.domain.PositionCombination p WHERE o.positionCombination=p.id and o.user=:user and o.tickTime in (SELECT MAX(s.tickTime) FROM com.uforic.optionstrader.domain.StrategyExitReport s group by s.positionCombination) group by p.strategyType]

How can I fix this ??

Comment: So it can't find FIELD "current_profit_percpa"; the message tells you this. Where is this field in your entity? You fix it by putting a valid field name in there

Comment: @BillyFrost its already there . And if I select that column without SUM function it works fine.

Comment: So post the Entity. As already said, you do not select a COLUMN! you select a FIELD

Comment: @BillyFrost the entity name was not proper . i changed it now . But getting another error now : "caanot create TypedQuery for more than one return"

Comment: I already defined constructor but still getting the error "cannot create TypedQuery for more than one return"